# read XML Response from server after POST data

Tags: vb.net, post, response, webclient

I am sending POST data to PHP webpage from my windows app using VB.net. The code is as follows:

```
Dim data As String = "this is a test data push"
Dim wc As New WebClient
wc.Headers(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType) = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
wc.UploadStringAsync(uri, data)
```

The data gets stored. In the PHP page, I am sending an XML response back to the phone

```
header('Content-type: text/xml');
        echo '';
        echo '<count>';
                      echo '<',$i,'>'
        echo '</count>';
        echo '';
```

How do I use WebClient to read the RESPONSE back? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subscribe to the `UploadStringCompleted` event.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144239.aspx for more details, but here is an excerpt:

> This method sends a string to a resource. The string is sent
>   asynchronously using thread resources that are automatically allocated
>   from the thread pool. Before uploading the string, this method
>   converts it to a Byte array using the encoding specified in the
>   Encoding property. **To receive notification when the string upload
>   completes, you can add an event handler to the UploadStringCompleted
>   event**.

Drilling farther in, you can see that even returns a `UploadStringCompletedEventArgs` object that includes the results via the `Result` property.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.uploadstringcompletedeventargs.aspx for more details.

Comment: Yes this is it! I am receiving the desired output. Can't thank you enough @tcarvin

Comment: Then throw me a bone and give me an upvote if it was useful :)